# _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1271, "Illegal mix of collations for operation ' IN '") in python

Tags: python, mysql

I have a MYSQL query in python. It worked fine. But, after deleting some tuple in the table, it makes following error.

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1271, "Illegal mix of collations for operation ' IN '")
```

Following is my code so far.

```
with open('out.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
for row in reader:
    text=(row['text'])
    emotion = (row['emotion'])
    my_list = (text, emotion)
    my_array = np.asarray(my_list)
    sentence = (text.lower())
    w_tokenize = (word_tokenize(sentence))

    negation_words = [w for i, w in enumerate(w_tokenize) if i and (
        w_tokenize[i - 1] in ["not", "never", "no", "nobody", "nothing", "neither", "doesn't", "isn't", "wasn't",
                        "shouldn't", "wouldn't", "couldn't", "won't", "can't", "don't", "didn't"])]

    if w_tokenize== []:
        Value = ''
    else:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        format_strings = ','.join(['%s'] * len(w_tokenize))
        cursor.execute("SELECT emotion_type FROM emotion WHERE key_word IN  (%s)" % format_strings,
                       tuple(w_tokenize))
        results = [res[0] for res in cursor.fetchall()]
        if results:
            frequencies = Counter(results)
            Value = max(frequencies, key=frequencies.get)
        else:
            Value = ''
```

But I couldn't find the solution for that. Can any one help me.

Comment: can you share your `w_tokenize`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you are calling `execute` the wrong way. You are passing in parameters via string formatting. That's very dangerous (leaves you open to SQL injection) and also leads to unexpected results. The correct way is

```
cursor.execute("SELECT emotion_type FROM emotion WHERE key_word IN  (%s)" , tuple(w_tokenize))
```

I think what you probably intended to pass as a parameter is `",".join(w_tokenize)`

```
cursor.execute("SELECT emotion_type FROM emotion WHERE key_word IN  (%s)" , ",".join(w_tokenize))
```

because what goes inside the IN clause should be a sub query or a comma separated string. The mysql connector will not automatically translated your tuple into a CSV

Comment: I tried from your way. But it also make error which is " query = query % db.literal(args)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"

Comment: you should use `",".join(w_tokenize)` please see the update

Comment: This isn't a very good question. We have no idea what your `w_tokenize` looks like, or what the generated SQL is (it will be in the error log). The general format is `SELECT emotion_type FROM emotion WHERE key_word IN  ('v1','v2','v3')`. Please use the guidelines provided to use the suitable variabels as appropriate or update your question with the required information.

Comment: is this sorted out now?

Comment: Not yet. The problem remain same as before.

Comment: Well then my previous comment still applies

Comment: The problem has automatically sorted out without doing any thing. I think it is a problem with my PHP myadmin server. Any way thank you for your consideration.

Comment: PHP myadmin is not a server. It is a client, so it has nothing to do with this. I think it's my answer that solved it :)